# pytest use arguments in sessionstart

Tags: arguments, pytest

I have a conftest.py file looking like this:

```
from testdevice import TestDevice
from pytest import fixture

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--n", action="store", default="Name")

@fixture()
def name(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--n")

def pytest_configure(config):
    """
    Allows plugins and conftest files to perform initial configuration.
    This hook is called for every plugin and initial conftest
    file after command line options have been parsed.
    """

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    """
    Called after the Session object has been created and
    before performing collection and entering the run test loop.
    """

    name = 'device_name'
    TestDevice(name)

def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    """
    Called after whole test run finished, right before
    returning the exit status to the system.
    """

def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    """
    called before test process is exited.
    """
```

I am testing an embedded device, using ssh in the tests. Before the test I want to prepare the device, using the class TestDevice(name). "name" is the key of a dictionary containing device information.

Instead of hardcoding name in sessionstart. I have created a fixture where i can access the name argument, however I am only able to use the fixture in the tests. I am not able to access the fixture in "pytest_sessionstart", as i am not able to access the "request" argument.

Can anything be done to access the python arguments on "pytest_sessionstart"?

Comment: Like this : pytest_sessionstart(session, name).

Comment: Exactly like that, but I get the error: pytest_sessionstart(session, name)
Argument(s) {'name'} are declared in the hookimpl but can not be found in the hookspec

Comment: Create a function which has this fixture passed in as parameter and returns the value. And witihin the session_start, call this new function.

Comment: You can use the session config, e.g. `session.config.getoption("--n")`. You cannot use a fixture in this hook (or other hooks).

Comment: Using session.config did the trick very easily. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use an extra fixture.

You can get name in pytest_sessionstart via session object:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
parser.addoption("--n", action="store", default="Name")

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
name = session.config.getoption('--n'):
TestDevice(name)
```